# Expecting Member Declaration with ArrayList

Tags: kotlin, arraylist

I am trying to create an `ArrayList` in a class, like so:

```
class ConvertableTests : BaseTest(){

   var categories = ArrayList<String>()
   categories.add('a') <---- //Expecting member declaration error here

   inner class ConvertableClass : Convertible...
```

Why I can't add objects to my array list after I initialize the list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add items into the list after you initialize the list *if* you aren't doing so at the root scope of the class. Same as if you would have tried to do the same thing in Java.

i.e.

```
//this won't work, like you just found out
class Example {
    var categories = ArrayList<String>()
    categories.add("a") // this isn't inside a function or an `init` block
}
```

You need to put it inside of a function or an `init` block

```
fun functionExample() {
    var categories = ArrayList<String>()
    categories.add("a") // This would work fine
}
```

or

```
class Example {
    var categories = ArrayList<String>()
    init {
        categories.add("a")
    }
}
```

To elaborate on Sergey's example of the `apply` and why that works if you don't do it inside of a function or an `init`

```
class Example {
    var categories = ArrayList<String>().apply {
        add("a") 
     } 
}
```

The kotlin compiler is performing an optimization and it's actually treating this as if you were putting it into an `init` block. If you decompile this and see what's happening, it's actually doing this

/// This is what it compiles back up to in Java
public Example() {
ArrayList var8 = new ArrayList();
var8.add("a");
this.category = var8;
}

Which is the same thing that happens when you use the `init` block.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `init` block to initialize array:

```
class ConvertableTests : BaseTest() {

    var categories = ArrayList<String>()
    init {
        categories.add("a")
    }
    // ...
}
```

Or `apply` extension function:

```
var categories = ArrayList<String>().apply {
    add("a") 
}
```

Also you should use double quotes `"` to add a `String`:

```
var categories = ArrayList<String>()
categories.add("a")
```

Single quotes are used for `Char`s:

```
var categories = ArrayList<Char>()
categories.add('a')
```

Comment: The `also` option worked, but can you elaborate on *why* this needs to happen?

Comment: It's semantic of Kotlin language. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html    https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#getters-and-setters